# I have a table with records. No matter which View button I click, the bottom record is displayed

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a table with a list of records.  Each record has a View button.  But no matter which View button I click, the bottom record (Acme6) gets opened?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crl9x.png)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are sharing datasource for your list and details pages. If my assumption is correct, then you need to modify your view button event handler as follow:

```js
// onClick event handler for View button
var rowItem = widget.datasource.item;
var listDatasource = widget.parent.parent.datasource;

listDatasource.selectKey(rowItem._key);
app.showPage(app.pages.DetailsPage);
```